# How to send username password to website from windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

Is it possible to get username and password from windows form and send them to a webpage and the webpage begins checking if the username and password is acceptable ... if it is true i switch to another windows form if its false i popup a messagebox to tell him check your username or password.    Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with RestSharp (https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp), a really nice library for simple REST requests.

Here's an example using this library:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("username", txtUsername.Text); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddParameter("password", txtPassword.Text); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Comment: what do you do if it's forms autentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible but it depends on the website you're calling to check the password. If it supplies a nice API for you to check the username/password with it can be really easy. If it's not it tends to get ugly pretty quick.

Do you know if a webservice/API is available for the website that's supposed to validate the credentials?

Comment: could you give a sample code or the classes that i'll be using

Comment: It depends on the website you're using. If it doesn't expose an API then you're stuck with something like soerenn posted. Could you be more specific about the website you're trying to work with?

Comment: just a login php page with username and password textboxes and login button